# why do i get weird result on type assertion in go lang?

Tags: go

This code works fine but, when I bind them in one case, for example:

```
var i interface{}
s := make([]map[string]interface{}, 5, 5)
i = s
switch x := i.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println("type is an array")
        fmt.Println("length is: ")
        fmt.Println(len(x))
    case []map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Println("type is an array")
        fmt.Println("length is: ")
        fmt.Println(len(x))
  }
```

but when I bind them in one case statement doesn't work

```
switch x := i.(type) {
case []interface{}, []map[string]interface{}:
    fmt.Println("type is an array")
    fmt.Println("length is: ")
    fmt.Println(len(x))
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Hi Sharad. Could you please elaborate more about your problem? We need a better clarity of the problem in order to help you properly

Answer (score 3):

See the language specification:

> The TypeSwitchGuard may include a short variable declaration. When that form is used, the variable is declared at the end of the TypeSwitchCase in the implicit block of each clause. In clauses with a case listing exactly one type, the variable has that type; otherwise, the variable has the type of the expression in the TypeSwitchGuard.

Also, remember that Go is statically typed. You cannot decide the type of the variable you declare in runtime. So if you list multiple types, it simply declares the variable using the same type as the switch variable.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue is here:

```
fmt.Println(len(x))
```

At runtime in the second version, Go doesn't know whether `x` is an `[]interface{}` or an `[]map[string]interface{}`, so it makes it simply an `interface{}`.  While the *underlying* type is an `[]` (of something), the actual type of `x` at this point is simply `interface{}`, and you can't call `len` on `interface{}`.